# How to Hide Divider when NSSplitView subview is Collapsed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nssplitview

OK, here's my problem :

I've been using **[DMSplitView](https://github.com/malcommac/DMSplitView)** for some `NSSplitView` manipulation. However when the rightmost view is collapsed, the divider (even if it's being pushed to the right) is still visible (yep, you might consider it an exaggeration but I still keep noticing that 1px line at the right of the window).

Is there any way to make it disappear?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple.

Just implement `- (BOOL)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView shouldHideDividerAtIndex:(NSInteger)dividerIndex` somewhere inside `DMSplitView.m` and makes sure it behaves as you wish.

Comment: Just FYI this does not work at all if the divider is not on the edge of the split view.